# How to implement a Pyspark script to truncate tables and insert data from a JSON file on a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input JSON file :

```
{
    "table_addresses": [
        {"id": 123, "firstname": "Mark", "lastname": "Zador", "address1": "via garibaldi 99", "address2": "", "city": "Rome", "zipcode": "00100"},
        {"id": 456, "firstname": "Kate","lastname": "Jess", "address1": "Via matteotti 99", "address2": "", "city": "Rome","zipcode": "00100"}
                  ],
    "table_product": [
        {"id": 1, "product_type": "type_X", "advisor": "N"},
        {"id": 2, "product_type": "type_Y", "advisor": "S"}
                  ]
}
```

Using Pyspark I have to write a script that has to :

- truncate the tables 'table_addresses' and 'table_product' previously
  created on a postgreSQL DB. **&**
- Read the json and insert data into each    table ('table_addresses'
  and 'table_product') respectively.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: I worry that this question is too generic. Maybe consider splitting into different questions, like "how to save from pyspark to postgres"

Comment: For the moment, the only way I've found is to implement the following instruction:

dataframe.write.jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})


 However, this way does not meet my requirement.